# Module not found: javafx.controls

Tags: java

I have downloaded JavaFX SDK, unpacked it and set a `PATH_TO_FX` system variable, following [this instructions](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx). I used following code example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(l), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Tried to compile it with the suggested pattern:

**javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java**

But compiler throws an error: module not found: javafx.controls. 
Windows 10. Java and JavaFX versions is 11.0.1

Again: I DID ADD the line **--add-modules javafx.controls**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module javafx.controls not found in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349773/module-javafx-controls-not-found-in-java-9)

Comment: Downloading and unpacking the JavaFX files (https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) worked for me. I have the following VM options: `--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.media,javafx.fxml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved in 3 steps.

1. Use **%PATH_TO_FX%** instead of **$PATH_TO_FX** in the command line.
2. Recreate the variables (both system and user) **PATH_TO_FX** enclosing its value in quotation marks. As the directory **"C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\"** contains a space, it caused an error "invalid flag".
3. Rebooting the computer to update the variables.

Answer (score 10):

I had to also include the 'lib' directory:  `--module-path %PATH_TO_FX%;%PATH_TO_FX%\lib`  to make it compile.

Comment: Thank you! On the Mac I had to adjust slightly: `--module-path $PATH_TO_FX:$PATH_TO_FX/lib`

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `gradle` and below `build.gralde` works fine for me (`org.beryx.jlink` is optional to build standalone distribution).

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.5'
    id "org.beryx.jlink" version "2.3.0"  //optional for jlink
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}

mainClassName = 'gui.Main'
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you don't have spaces in your list of modules:

```
--module-path PATH_TO_JAVAFX/lib --add-modules javafx.swing,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.controls
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I use Maven, I had to modify the pom.xml file to include the dependency.

`pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You may need to modify the version numbers according to what version you have installed.

Comment: Might need to add `javax-web` dependency also in `pom.xml` in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

As JavaFX isn't included in "default" JDK's I found the easiest fix for this kind of issues is to use the LibericaJDK (11+) from Bellsoftware which has the JavaFX included again to make it easier to develop and run JavaFX applications.

https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-11.0.4/

Answer (score 0):

helloFX.bat
@echo off
cls
set PATH_TO_FX="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"
C:
cd \development\java\javaFX

rem javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml HelloFX.java
javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java

java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX

pause

Comment: Would you add some expression? It is actually hard to follow with only command line example, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When running the command

```
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java
```

instead of writing the `$PATH_TO_FX or %PATH%` write the path itself that is

```
javac --module-path C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java
```

Also try to make sure your directory doesn't have any spaces. It gave me problems, it may work for you for a directory with spaces

Comment: can we run that javac under netbeans configuration anyway? @r_goyal?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was little different from above:
`javac --module-path C:\other_program\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib\ --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java`
I had to put `lib` in the path, and not `C:\other_program\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\` together like [Arilou suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60509592/5595995).

To execute the compiled file, "HelloFX.class", you may include the `lib` path as well:
`java --module-path C:\other_program\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib\ --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX`

Runtime environemnt:
  OS: Windows 10
  PowerShell
  Java 15.0.1
  JavaFX 17.01

Answer (score 0):

I am using maven. I had to add this dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>19-ea+2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Download and install the JavaFX SDK from the official OpenJFX website:   https://openjfx.io/
2. In IntelliJ, open your project and go to File > Project Structure.
3. Select "Modules" from the left-hand side and then click the "+" button to add a new module.
4. Select "JARs or directories" and browse to the "lib" folder in your JavaFX SDK installation directory.
5. Select all the JAR files in the "lib" folder and click "OK".
6. IntelliJ will now add the JAR files to your project's classpath.

This should do the job....This is for IntelliJ but this works for other IDEs as well or at least in a similar way..

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Netbeans, its a must to uncheck "Compile on Save", unless you get this error.

https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/91#issuecomment-537354974

If you want a screenshot

https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/120#issuecomment-692805305

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer instead of just providing links