# Error "JavaFX.controls not found" when I run app from CMD

Tags: java, javafx, cmd

I'm trying to run a JavaFX app through CMD but I can't make it work.
What I did so far:

1) followed this [guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) and added the new environment variable (the JavaFX folder is in the desktop, does this make a difference?)

2) Tried to compile with `javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java` The HelloFX app is [here](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java)

But I get an error saying "Module not found: JavaFX.controls". Does somebody know how can I solve that? (Also Javafx.controls.jar is in the JavaFX's lib folder).

Comment: Reboot computer after set variables to PATH.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055598/module-not-found-javafx-controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a solution: if instead of %PATH_TO_FX% I put the full path to the JavaFX's lib folder (as an example: "C:\Desktop\JavaFX12.0.1\lib") being careful to put the path in the quotation marks, it works.

I don't understand why this happens so if somebody knows I would be thankful if they could share.

Comment: Did you do this: `set PATH_TO_FX="C:\Desktop\JavaFX12.0.1\lib"` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Lorenzo's solution works for me, the path of javafx lib goes in compile and then run command instead of %PATH_TO_FX% with "path".

Practically:

for compile(with my javafx lib path):

```
javac --module-path "C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-14\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java
```

for run:

```
java --module-path "C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-14\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution on Mac was:

Compile:

```
javac --module-path Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls fileName.java
```

Run:

```
java --module-path Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls fileName
```

JavaFx path: Desktop/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib. (As the Java folder is on the Desktop and I have previously configured my directory to the Desktop, the path began with the folder name without the simple slash </>.)